# How can I escape double quotes on command line to .vbs script?

Tags: windows, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have a script.  I want to send a line with double quotes inside it to that script, like this: Cscript myScript.vbs "Testing "this line""

But the double quotes inside the line make it so the line never gets to the script properly.  I've tried escaping with a carat (^) or using double double-quotes ("Testing ""this line""") with different results, but none is the result I want (the script getting Testing "this line").

To justify why I need to do this, I'm trying to send an SQL line to a script that will edit my Orca table, and there needs to be double quotes in one of the values to do what I want to do with Orca.

Answer (score 6):

You could try this:

Here is the vb script x.vbs:

```
Wscript.Echo Unescape(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
```

Here is the output for running it:

```
D:\>cscript x.vbs "Testing %22this line%22"
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Testing "this line"
```

If you replace all " with %22 you will be able to use this method to pass the double quotes in.

Comment: When calling vbscript from inside a batch file you can use %%22 instead of ". Note the double percentage sign - here % is used to escape itself.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done. I have tried everything and the only way to make this work is to designate some string of characters to represent " in your VBS and replace the command line arguments instance of the designated string with ". I picked something that would not likely be a problem :!: was the string i used to represent ".

In my code, I added the following:

```
strArgu0 = Wscript.Arguments(0)
strOldSTR = Replace(strArgu0,":!:","""")
```

Answer (score -1):

Examples I've seen use a backslash before a quote to escape it.  A common example of this is passing logging options to a setup program (Windows installer package)

```
Setup.exe /v"/l*v \"c:\My Log Files\test.log\" /qn"
```